# Group policy for Windows updates is missing some entries

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I'm doing some work on an older Windows Active Directory domain that's been upgraded from Windows Server 2016 domain controllers to 2019 although the forest/domain is still at 2016 level. Group policy, esp. around Windows updates, seems to be out of date. This is the list you get on a clean/test domain set-up:

[image: Windows updates policy settings on new domain]

But on the existing legacy domain, it's got far fewer entries and some of the entries themselves have different options:

[image: Windows updates policy settings on legacy domain]

I've tried the re-registering of DLLs mentioned but that doesn't help. How to I update/refresh the group policy settings so that it's up to date?

Comment: It's determined by the ADMX files. By default, ADMX files are retrieved from the local machine. In GPMC when you are editing a policy, left pane, Policies > Administrative Templates, where does it say the ADMX files are retrieved from?

Comment: Your ADMX templates are out of date.

Comment: It says the policies are retrieved from the central store: https://i.imgur.com/tmWDbUW.png

Comment: But yes, the admx templates are indeed out of date - just looked in \\mydomain\sysvol\middle-earth.co.uk\Policies\PolicyDefinitions and the latest file is dated 14th Nov 2015 ;-)